# Why is it bad to call a function in the condition of a for loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I recently asked an Application Architect at work to review a `php` script I had written to automate some tasks I do weekly in our Help Desk department.

In his review he stated

> `## Loops`
>
> `Your loops are good, you didn't do anything bad like calling functions in the condition`
>
> `for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++); is BAD`

Honestly, I've never been tempted to do that in my code before but it made me wonder why it would be bad.

I assume it's because, the result of a function might be any value at all and it seems like a perfect way to create an infinite loop and just in general cause unexpected behaviour.

I tried googling but couldn't find any relevant results so I ask:

**Why is it bad to call a function in the condition of a for loop?**

**Note** the `count($array)` in the comment itself is, to me, a gimme. Of course, you'd want to just cache that. More specifically, I mean in the context of using other more complex functions.

For those that will surely wonder *"Why not just ask the guy who wrote it"*, he's super busy and already took the time to help me, I don't want to push that too far with *"Now, can you please explain all of your comments to me?"*

Comment: Cause function called again and again on every loop iteration, no?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is offtopic and better on codereview. Anyway, its because you'll call the function at every iteration of the loop, with the additional overhead it brings. Just store the count() result outside the loop and use the variable

Comment: The only reason for avoiding it, to my opinion, is the fact that e.g. _count($array)_ has to be evaluated every time the _for_ is performed, while it obviously would be evaluated only once if done outside of the loop.

Comment: Because it's **slower** than calculating function result once and using the value in the condition.

Comment: @DamienPirsy This question is **miles** off-topic on Code Review. Please review [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons I can think of:

- The return value of a function can vary, so you cannot be certain your loop will remain finite
- The return type is not guarenteed in some languages, so you have another opportunity for undefined behaviour
- It is usually less performant (especially in the `count()` example)
- It reduces readability, because a developer now needs to review and understand the function just to know how many times the loop should run
- I cannot think of ANY legitimate examples of why you would actually need the return value of a function, every time the condition is evaluated
- The number of iterations cannot be (easily) determined at run-time, because the function must be called again at the end of each iteration

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, the `count($array)` in the comment itself was, to me, a gimme. I should have been more specific but I meant using other more complex function

Comment: Yep, I figured that based on your rep. I'll try to find more examples.

Comment: One possible legitimate example : if you add some elements in the array.

Comment: @A.L In many languages arrays are immutable. In PHP, if you were to implement code in the example and then append elements, your loop would continue to run for the new length of the array. But consider you are extending the number of iterations now. Think how difficult this would be to follow, when you have to mentally compute every single iteration to consider whether or not the loop will execute even more times, because an iteration could cause more iterations. This would significantly exacerbate the problem, so I don't consider this a legitimate reason.

Answer (score 6):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++); //is not efficient
```

Yes, this is not efficient to use because in every iteration function being called which is not good. You need to execute this function one time.

```
$count = count($array);
for ($i= 0; $i < $count; $i++); //is much efficient
```

Because in this code `count` function will execute one time. In your previous code `count` function execute multiple times.

Comment: Added +1 but I  should have been more specific

Comment: You got answer from @deed02392. Need more specific?

Comment: No, sorry, I was just saying your answer was perfect for *the question I original asked* which later realized I needed to word a bit better. ;)

Comment: I assume the same applies to other languages like C++?

Answer (score 3):

It is better to count the values in advance because if you put it in the loop, the function will be executed on every iteration to check if the condition is met.

In this example, the count function is not too heavy and won't slow your program down (unless it's a big array), but watch out with bigger functions.

Comment: It is. But other functions are not.

Comment: Added +1 but I  should have been more specific